# Laravel Blade Component, "File name is longer than the maximum allowed path length" on CentOS

Tags: php, laravel, centos, laravel-blade

I have a bug in Laravel occurring only on CentOS servers (at least, I never saw on Debian...).

It is about large Blade templates applied to Blade Components: if the length of the template's string, combined with the path of the views' folder, is longer than `PHP_MAXPATHLEN` chars, [this call](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L30) of `file_exists()` fails with an error like `File name is longer than the maximum allowed path length on this platform (4096)`.

The issue is exactly [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/View/Component.php#L77), has been discussed [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32254) and my [pull request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/43594) to fix it has been rejected (!).

So: is there any flag, configuration or whatever that may be in the PHP-FPM package of CentOS that make `file_exists()` fail with a fatal error when a path longer than `PHP_MAXPATHLEN` chars is used?